# PHP encoder - Viewing some problem

Tags: php, javascript, html, encoder

I am using a free [PHP Encoder](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/PHPEncoder.aspx) for testing my encoded script.

My script (in the one PHP file) is something like this :

```
<?php

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

As you see my HTML (with JavaScript inside) are under the PHP code.

When I encoded that file with PHPEncoder it seems many problems appear in HTML and JavaScript, not PHP.

What is the best way for encoding this file?

Comment: Use it only on php code. Btw you are not gonna protect yourself from ripping your code.

Comment: i do that // that works // but what about html encoding?

Comment: You want to encode the HTML as well??

Answer (score 0):

try something useful like

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

to check whether everything works fine.

Comment: hi / every thing was fine before encoding / but after that i had many problems / i checked these : 1- i put all html codes inside the php code (in a variable and echo that variable) --> before encode = ok , after that = down  ------ 2- i just encoded php code --> before encode = ok , after encode = ok

Comment: but what can i do about html code ? i know every body can decode that file / but i just want do this /

Answer (score 0):

Is the php code using the "print" or "echo" functions?

That would cause problems. Any content which is part of the information on the web page should be between the `<body>` tags.

It is however, quite safe to put a `<?php ?>` block inside the body of a .php file.

Comment: I needed to comment the tags, perhaps my answer will be more useful now.